# JPA Inheritence IdClass

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

How to use IdClass in multiple inheritance entity composite key case ?

```
    @IdClass(IdClassEntity1.class)
    class Entity1 {
    private long e1pk1;
    private long e1pk2;
    }
    @IdClass(IdClassEntity2.class)
    class Entity2 extends Entity1  {
    private long e2pk1;
    private long e2pk2;
    }
    class Entity3 extends Entity2 {
    private long e3pk1;
    private long e3pk2;
    }
```

what should be IdClassEntity2 :

```
class IdClassEntity2 {
        private long e1pk1;
        private long e1pk2;
        private long e2pk1;
        private long e2pk2;
}
```

or

```
class IdClassEntity2 {
        private IdClassEntity1 idClassEntity1;
        private long e2pk1;
        private long e2pk2;
}
```

Comment: They are mapped by default, just add MappedSuperClass or @Entity, dont need to redefine in the subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `@MappedSuperClass` or `@Entity` to declare the `@IdClass`. The pk is propagated via inheritance.

For example, using `@MappedSuperClass`, you can do the following:

```
@MappedSuperClass
@IdClass(IdClassEntity1.class)
public class Entity1 {
    @Id private long e1pk;    
    @Id private long e1pk;
    ...

 @Entity
 public class Entity2 extends Entity1 {
    ...
```

Using `@Entity`, follow the same paradigm

Comment: So SubClass Hierarchy can not define thier own Pk with Super PK means : Super(PK1,PK2) , SubClass1(PK3) and SubClass2(PK4)

Comment: @hiddenuser: No they cannot define their PK. All entity classes in the hierarchy share the same composite key from the `@MappedSuperclass` entity so that you can i.e. invoke `em.find()` on them. From database point of view all entity instances from the hierarchy are stored in the same table and each entity type is recognized by discriminator. Take into consideration that you cannot instantiate and query `Entity1` as it is not persistent.

Comment: This is a huge limitation, IMHO. SubClasses should define their own additional PK